# passing data btw classes using request.setParameter, request.getParameter

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 java classes and I want to transfer data between them.

I take user id as parameter in a previous jsp form, and in a java class, using setAttribute I create a atribute named st_id.

then in another java clas I want to retrieve this data, but I get null.pointer exception.

first java file;

```
public class Signin implements Action {

public String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Student stu = new StDAO().getUser(request.getParameter("st_id").toString());
    request.setAttribute("st_id", request.getParameter("st_id").toString());
...
```

second;

```
public class addCourseStu implements Action{

@Override
public String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
       TakeCourseDAO pf = new TakeCourseDAO();
       String s= (String) request.getAttribute("st_id");
```

So s is null, it's not my intention.

Comment: I removed the _jdbc_ tag from your question, please only add tags that are relevant to your question.

Comment: A request exists from the time the web browser sends it to the web server until the web server (via the servlet) has made its response. Are you sure the attribute is accessed within the scope?

Comment: It's not, thanks.  I thought request was a somehow universal variable @SparkOn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request exists from the time the web browser sends it to the web server until the web server (via the servlet) has made its response.Every request for a servlet has its own accessibilty scope. From a servlet, you can:

1. add new attributes to the request's scope
2. obtain exisiting attributes from the request's scope
3. remove exisiting attributes from the request's scope
   As you are getting null it is quite obvious that the attribute is not accessed within the scope.

You can try alternatives like Session scope or Application scopes which ever suits you

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want to do but I gather that you want to maintain some state on the server between two requests right?

Look into sessions & cookies for this.

What you do here is weird as it seems you are setting an attribute on an **incoming** request in the first file.

Comment: I want to use request just as I use session in php. I want to bind a string called "st_id" and reach its value from another class. but i think i have a conceptual problem about it.

I just tried in this code: 1)  edit the incoming request 2) get that edited request in another file.

Comment: First google hit for `java sessions servlet tutorial`: http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting